# Error in dnorm: How to deal with Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, mle

everyone.I want to use dnorm in R to make a maximum likelihood estimation for ols,but it shows that "Non-numeric argument to mathematical function",I wonder if you can give some help to my code.

Although many books show that we can use mle to estimate ols byhand,I wonder if dnorm can be used as nomalden in stata.And dnorm is also an important part in my whole likelihood function.

The following if my code:

```
slope1 <- -.3;slope2 <- .3;slope3 <- 1.8; slope4 <- 0.5;intercept1 <- 1.5    # generating data from C_1
age <- sample(seq(-2,2,len=201), 40)
grade <- sample(seq(-2,2,len=201), 40)
not_smsa <- sample(seq(-2,2,len=201), 40)
wage <- intercept1 + slope1*age +slope2*grade + slope3*not_smsa + rnorm(length(age),0,.15) # add some noise

# model matrix `X` and response `Y`
X <- cbind(1, age , grade , not_smsa )
Y <- wage
K<- ncol(X)
mydata <- cbind.data.frame(X,Y)
# initial guess on coefficients
ans <- lm(wage ~ age + grade + not_smsa, 
          data = mydata)
vi <- c(coef(ans))
#log likelihood function
ols.nll <- function (beta) {
  eta <- (Y-X %*% beta)/sigma
  p <- dnorm(Y,eta,sigma)
  -sum(log(p),na.rm=T)
}
#mle
fit <- optim(vi, ols.nll , method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
fit$par
```

Thank you for your attention,I am looking forward to your help

Comment: You haven't defined `sigma`. So, it's being considered as the function `stats::sigma`. You can't divide by a function, and hence the error. By the way, I obtained this error `Error in (Y - X %*% beta)/sigma : non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.As a freshman in R,I wonder  if you can fix my code directly,many thanks!

Comment: Just provide the sd you want to use instead of `sigma`. I think that'll be enough.

Comment: the latex code is :\sigma ^{2}=\frac{{(y-X\beta) }'(y-X\beta)}{N} .you can also refer the function 53 in page13  of this link:http://www.sherrytowers.com/mle_introduction.pdf . many thanks again

Comment: this question has been solved。thanks to stack overflow and Mr.yarnabrina